# How to set capabilities for a container in cdk8s?

Tags: kubernetes, cdk8s

In YAML I'd do this:

```yaml
securityContext:
    capabilities:
        add:
            - NET_ADMIN
```

Example in k8: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-capabilities-for-a-container

How do I achieve this with [ckd8s](https://cdk8s.io/)?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't currently possible.

From https://github.com/cdk8s-team/cdk8s-plus/issues/1168:

> `Capabilities` are not yet supported by `cdk8s-plus`, so escape hatches
> are the way to go.